# Offset after georeferencing of an old maritime map of Quebec

Tags: georeferencing, historical-maps, transverse-mercator

For some time, I have been trying to georeference an old map of Quebec. On photo 1, there is the indication on the projection.
Map from 1936-1937, with small corrections in 1946

[image: On the Transverse Mercator projection]

I use the coordinate grid present on the map (Photo 2)

[image]

I tried many projections, many coordinate systems and in the best case I get an offset of several hundred meters on my georeferencing

I tried with :

- NAD27(CGQ77)/UTM zone 19N
- NAD27/ UTM zone 19N
- WGS84/ UTM zone 19N
  but without conclusive results

I must have missed a step, but I don't know which one.

Which projection and which coordinate system would you use to get the best result?

Comment: Is this data available online? can create a custom projection based on the info. What GIS software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is just using the screenshot image:
(if can have a higher resolution will be more accurate)

**WGS 84 / UTM zone 21N**

Using QGIS 3.26.2 Georeferencer

[image]